# How to ask if there is a leave

Tags: american-english, sentence-choice

**On monday, the company is off?**
I guess this doesn't seem right in English. What I want to convey is there is an official holiday on Monday. How can I do that?

Comment: 'Is Monday a public holiday?' 'Is the office closed on Monday?'

Comment: As Kate Bunting says. Or (in the UK) we might ask, 'Is the company taking (this) Monday off?'